# How do I rotate the camera around an object in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm just learning the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification, and I have a camera class in my iPhone application. So...i've found glu.h and glu.m for my app. This class includes two well-known functions gluLookAt and gluPerspective.

I'm trying to figure out how to spin the camera around a 3-D triangle using touch events.  I believe that using `touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIIvent *)event` is a good place to start, for instance.

Does anyone have any tutorials or literature they can suggest on how to solve my problem?